# Facebook FQL: Get the post_id where a photo with ID XXX is used as attachment

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a special problem and hope, someone can help me out of this.

My target: I have an object_id of a photo (and the pid and aid) and I want to know which posting on a page has this photo as attachment.

My current status:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, type, attachment FROM stream WHERE 1 
AND post_id = "111111_222222"
AND source_id = 111111
AND attachment.fb_object_id = "111111_333333"
AND type = 247
```

This leads me to the posting, which has the photo as attachment. Obviously, cause I am searching with the "post_id".
But if I remove the 'AND post_id = "111111_222222"' Facebook sends me no data.

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, type, attachment FROM stream WHERE 1 
AND source_id = 111111
AND attachment.fb_object_id = "111111_333333"
AND type = 247
```

Does anybody know, how to get the post_id where a photo with ID XXX is used as attachment.

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky because `stream` only goes back so far. This seems to be more of a bug / unstable nature of FQL data.

Try your call with this

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, type, attachment FROM stream WHERE 1 
AND source_id = "80329313253"
AND attachment.fb_object_id= "80329313253_11264130"
AND type = 247
```

And you can see it works.

Consider filing a bug to see what Facebook employees have to say about it

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think the FQL data is unstable sometimes too. I hope FB will work on this.
I have tested your query and it seems to be a step in the right direction. With your query as imagination I did some research and found a way, which you can see in the next answer. Another possible way I think ;-)

Comment: Another way of getting the post_id:

SELECT
post_id
FROM stream
WHERE 1
AND source_id = 111111
AND strpos(permalink,"https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=XXX") >=0

The "strpos ... >=0" is the "MySQL LIKE" of FQL ;-)